# iis 7 redirect (?) issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have a mvc app which runs here:

```
sometestingdemo.bla.com/mvcapp
```

on our test server. It usually runs at the 'top domain level' of the production server like this:

```
bladibla.com
```

The html that mvc produces contains code like this:

```
<link href="/content/css/global/somecoolstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This works obviously fine for the production server but not the test server. What are my options to fix this (ideally without changing the mvc code - if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Url.Content()` helper produces relative path to the root of the virtual directory in which the application is hosted in IIS. So if on your test environment you host your application on a `mvcapp` virtual directory that will still produce correct output.

You are using an url helper and not hardcoding the location to this CSS, aren't you? Here's the correct way to link a CSS file:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/content/css/global/somecoolstyles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Of course if you are using ASP.NET MVC 4 (which relies on Razor v2.0) you could also simplify this to:

```
<link href="~/content/css/global/somecoolstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

which will implicitly use the url helper to generate correct path.

If on the other hand you have hardcoded the url to this CSS file, then I am afraid that you are pretty much toasted here.

Comment: I am using Url.Content. Not sure whether the folder is a virtual directory. It is a folder under the default website which I made an application folder.

Comment: No, you should make this `mvcapp` folder being the virtual directory.

Comment: sorry my iis skills are limited. do you have a link to a 'recipe' for that. in particular for my 'subdomain/folder' situation. as i said there are no issue with the production server but on the test server. things are shared ...

Comment: You have a website in IIS, right? This is already a virtual directory. This website is mapped to a physical folder, for example `c:\inetpub`.  Now let's suppose that you want to deploy your application in the `c:\inetpub\mvcapp` folder. In the IIS management console you right click on the website and select to create a virtual directory. You give this virtual directory a name (`mvcapp` in your case), map it to the `c:\inetpub\mvcapp` physical folder and you deploy your MVC application in this folder.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's what I did. You have to make it an application right?

Comment: Sorry me again. My mvcapp is a (sub) virtual directory of the default website and I use: href="@Url.Content("~/... This produces link href="/content/css/global/styles.css" which is correct right. For some reason everyone is redirected (?) to the default website. do you think there is something wrong with the iis global (?) setting?

Comment: No, @Url.Content doesn't produce correct href. In your test environment it should produce `href="/mvcapp/content/css/global/styles.css"` because your MVC application must be hosted in a virtual directory called `mvcapp`.

Comment: thanks. That makes sense. Do you know what could be the reason for this unexpected behaviour? I have not written this app ... I guess the routing part is responsible ...

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with routing. It's your IIS configuration and the way this application has been deployed.

Comment: thanks. out of interest, how does asp.net mvc 'know' that it should produce: mvcapp/content/css/global/styles.css rather than /content/css/global/styles.css. also, would you happen to know which part of iis 7 I need to reconfigure?

Comment: It uses the current context Application information such as the base url. This information is populated by the ASP.NET hosting environment.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer and comments pointed me in the right direction. I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335271/configure-iis-7-to-produce-correct-urls-for-aps-net-mvc-3-app